# What are the ways to expose GraphQL Schema as REST api?

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, node-modules, rest

I have Graphql api developed and want to expose few REST API endpoints from it. so here my intention is use same Graphql logic to expose it as rest api. So far I got posts about using sofa to achieve this and want to check if there is any NestJS or Graphql existing package which we can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you've structured your application thus far. In general, NestJS promotes an N-tier architecture where business logic belongs inside of Services/Providers. When structured this way, it becomes relatively straightforward to share logic between GraphQL resolvers and HTTP controllers.

Resolvers and Controllers should act purely as routing components that receive requests/data and pass them to the appropriate service for processing.

```js
@Resolver()
class MyResolver {
   constructor(private readonly service: MyService) { }

   @Query()
   doSomething() {
     return this.service.doSomething();
   }
}

@Controller()
class MyController {
   constructor(private readonly service: MyService) { }

   @Get()
   doSomething() {
     return this.service.doSomething();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have developed a GraphQL API , which you then want to expose as REST , or you want to integrate a REST API in your GraphQL API? If it's the first one , you are totally missing the point of GraphQL. If it's the second one , then you need to pass the context argument in your Apollo Server constructor , containing a `dataSource` argument. Then you have to define a class that extends `RESTDataSource` (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/).

Comment: Thank you for the your quick help on it.  I am looking for first case. I have an application, which is relay on REST api and others are using my Graphql api. I just want to expose few REST endpoints for that application, but want to use same Graphql logic for it instead writing separate one.